# Flutter how to align Column to nested inside another Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create this effect.

[image]

I'm currently have this effect.

[image]

And this is my code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 30,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Recipes'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

);
```

I'm open to any Widget I'm new and I come from a React background thats why I'm using Row and Columns. Also its putting a nested Column a good idea. Do Flutter have a

tag to put the recipe name?

Comment: If I do that that will apply the rule to all childrens and I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Try out below **`code`**:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
      child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,  // added this line here instead of child column
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 30,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('Recipes'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

);
```

Comment: And use sizedBox widget for space

Answer (score 0):

You are using `crossAxisAlignment` at the inner `Column`. Instead of that You have to apply `crossAxisAlignment` at outer `Column`.

Note: Flutter apply your margin and padding in priority based. So outer `Column` has more priority than inner `Column`

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
          child: Column(
            // use alignment here
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.more_horiz,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Recipes'),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your Text Widget with **Align** widget and give **alignment** to centerLeft. And remove crossAxisAlignment from inner column..
i have provided the code below..

```
Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.more_horiz,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Recipes',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```